# mapView.setRegion in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I am having problems with my code in Swift 4, Xcode 9. Can someone help me?
When I run this program it gives me an error.

It says `mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)` is not working and giving my an error and when I comment that out, it works with my current location but just not zoomed in closely.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[0]
        if !isInitialized {
            isInitialized = true
            let span:MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)
            let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
            let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
            mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
            self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true
        }
}
```

Comment: What is the error it's showing? I implemented your code and it works fine for me. The only thing I can think of is that your mapView isn't attached.

Comment: Does it zoom into your location? and my error is fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value next to mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

Comment: try guard let location = locations.first else {return} instead let location = locations[0]

Comment: That did not work but I got it to work with connecting to the storyboard

Answer (score 2):

I'll bet you just forgot to link up your mapView with the storyboard. Make sure it's connected properly as an @IBOutlet and try again.

Comment: I do have this in my code.                                                                
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

Comment: Is it connected to the mapView on the storyboard? Having the line in code is not enough by itself.
What is the error you are getting?